# Having trouble trying to execute a simple HelloWorld.py file from Windows cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line

I am very new to python and I am trying to execute a python file called HelloWorld.Py. The code within the file editor is

```
#! Python3
print('Hello world!')
```

I am trying to do this from my windows command line. The correct path from what I can tell in my documents application is C:\Users\china\PythonFiles\HelloWorld.py.

As I am following a Udemy course, it is recommended that you type py.exe C:/Users/china/PythonFiles/HelloWorld.py (filled in with my example).

At first, I returned a syntax error for the use of py.exe. Reading online made me confused about what to put in front of C:, and after removing py.exe, and just typing C:/Users/china/PythonFiles/HelloWorld.py returns the error 'Unable to create process using 'Python3 "C:\Users\china\PythonFiles\HelloWorld.py" '

What am I doing wrong? I have researched online for a few hours and I am still no closer to figuring it out. Please help!

Comment: Please add your HelloWorld.py file (edit your question), so I can take a look at the code. Seems like there might be a problem with your script.

Comment: Fixed to include code I wrote in the file. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comment, or change it to `#!python3`.  `py.exe` doesn't like the capitalization.

The comment isn't needed unless you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, and it hints to `py.exe` which Python to use, but requires lowercase `python` followed by the major and optionally minor version, e.g `#!python3.6` or `#!python3`.  If the comment is missing, the latest version of Python installed wiil be used.